# I want to read and write an encrypted image file in sd card in android

Tags: java, android, encryption

i want to save an image taken from gallery and convert that image into encrypted string. The encrypted string which is too large  which i want to write inside sd card using the following code

```
            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/"
                    + folder_name);
            try {
                 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dir);
                 OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
                 osw.write(getImageDetails.getImage_details());
                 osw.flush();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

then i tried to read that encrypted string from sd card using the following code:

```
         FileReader rdr;
         StringBuffer stringBuffer;
         try {
            rdr = new FileReader("/sdcard/"+ folder_name+"/"+file.getName());
            BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(rdr);
            String line = "";
            stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            while ((line = bfr.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuffer.append(line);
                            }
             } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               }
```

when i tried to  display string using the following code

```
     System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
```

i can get part of that encrypted  string which i tried to write into SD card.
How can i get the whole encrypted string from sd card?

Comment: You can encode your image to base64 string and write it in file.

Comment: Actually i convert the image in the form of bitmap to String using base64. Then i encrypt that string and save it into sd card

Comment: Your code seems correct, are you sure you are writing the whole encrypted string to file (try putting it in txt file for testing and check).